# Summation with restrictions

Tags: summation

I am a beginner with Mathematica, so I apologise in advance if this question might sound trivial for most people. I am interested in evaluating a sum of the form

$$\underset{j \, \equiv \, n \pmod2}{\sum_{j=0}^{k/2}\sum_{n=-j}^{j}}f(n)g(j)$$

with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $j\in\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}$, subject to the restriction $j\equiv n \pmod2$. Also the step in the sum is $1/2$.

My question is how do I perform a sum with a restriction like this in Mathematica?

Comment: I tried for example `Sum[1,{n,Mod[-j,2],Mod[j,2],1/2}]` but I realized that the step $1/2$ is added to the the result of `Mod[...]` and not to $j$. Well as I said I am just a beginner with Mathematica.

Comment: Is the step in both sums 1/2?

Comment: Not sure the equation makes sense. j restricted to n(mod 2) means j takes values {0,1/2,1,3/2}, but what if k = 1,000,000?

Comment: @MikeY Yes the step is 1/2 in both sums. Say k=1 then 

$$\underset{j \, \equiv \, n \pmod2}{\sum_{j=0}^{1/2}\sum_{n=-1/2}^{1/2}}f(n)g(j)$$

This will give 

$$f(0)g(0)+\underset{1/2 \, \equiv \, n \pmod2}{\sum_{n=-1/2}^{1/2}}f(n)g(1/2)=f(0)g(0)+f(1/2)g(1/2)$$

Comment: What if k=6? How does that summation work?

Comment: @MikeY Well let's take the largest value then, $k=6$. This means that $n\in\{ 0,\pm1/2,\pm1, \pm3/2, \pm2, \pm5/2, \pm3\}$ and using the restriction that $3 \equiv n \pmod2$, then the allowed values for $n$ that will be used in the sum are $n\in\{ \pm1,\pm3 \}$.

Comment: @MikeY of course, there will be all the previous terms for $j<3$, i.e. $0,1/2,...,5/2$ with the analogous restrictions on $n$ and only those $n$ will contribute in the sum. I just wrote the largest of them to show you how it works, or I believe it works. I have a small doubt because of the half-integers involved in the congruence relation. That is, I am not sure yet if I am to use $j\equiv n \pmod2$ to mean that $j=n-2\lfloor n\rfloor$ or that of modular inverses, whenever $j$ is a half-integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd write

```
Sum[If[Mod[j, 2] == Mod[n, 2], f[n] g[j], 0], {j, 0, k/2, 1/2}, {n, -j, j, 1/2}]
```

Let k=3;

```
f[0] g[0] + f[1/2] g[1/2] + f[-1] g[1] + f[1] g[1] + f[-(1/2)] g[3/2] + f[3/2] g[3/2]
```